# MarkLogic Automatic Login with LDAP authentication

Tags: authentication, marklogic, marklogic-8

I've set up LDAP authentication on an HTTP MarkLogic app, and I am able to log in to the application using my Active Directory credentials when prompted to log in.
I would like to get rid of the log-in prompt and have the app automatically use the windows credentials of the current logged in user for authentication.
Is that possible?